# how insert `thead` before inserting the `tbody` with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have made a project to select data from database into a table. i use jquery i just made the code for select the data to the table. but now i have a problem. i dont know how to fill thead before inserting the tbody that can fit with the tbody item.

this my code to select data from database i use jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/absen/spl_inputselect_data.php",
    success: function(data) {
      var list = JSON.parse(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        var tr = "<tr>";

        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['no'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['nama'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['tanggal'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['jam_mulai'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['jam_selesai'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['status'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['total'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['bagian'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['cost'] + "</td>";
        tr += "<td>" + list[i]['tugas'] + "</td>";
        tr += "</tr>";
        $("#check_data tbody").append(tr);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do the same just change `tbody` to `thead`

Comment: Have you tried `$("#check_data thead").append()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add using `insertBefore` of jquery like

```
$('thead').insertBefore( "table tbody");
```

Comment: in my code where i must place that code?

Comment: You want to add `thead` so can put outside of for loop

Comment: Done,,,.... Thx dude

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is `prepend()` method:

```
$('table').prepend('thead');
```